# Why do integer div and mod round towards zero?

Tags: java, integer-division

Unlike in C, in Java is the result of `x/y` and `x%y` well-defined even for negative operands. Surprisingly, it's defined by rounding towards zero, and not by rounding down (i.e., towards negative infinity). Does anybody have taken any advantage of this definition?

<sup>In most cases I just don't care, but sometimes I had to work around this, e.g., when computing an index using modulo `array.length`.</sup>

<sup>This is no rant, I'm really interested if there are uses for this definition.</sup>

Comment: that's how it's done in the hardware. one small thing, try to keep you array.length a power of 2 and use &(array.length-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easier to implement a division routine if you can round toward zero.  Often, a division involving a negative is sign-flipped, and then the division carried out on a positive equivalent, and then the answer flipped back again.  So the effect is naturally going to be round toward zero.

Comment: That's true, however, such a definition is a common source of errors and doing it otherwise would not be that expensive. I still wonder if there's anybody having taken any advantage of this (strange but standard) definition?

Comment: @maaartinus: The first thing that comes to mind is that round-toward-zero will give unbiased quantization error (assuming data is evenly distributed between +ve and -ve), whereas round-toward-minus-infinity will result in a bias.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example where it's useful, however slightly:

```
maxPage = (rows.length - 1) / ROWS_PER_PAGE
```

(No need to special case for `maxPage = 0` when `rows.length = 0`, assuming `ROWS_PER_PAGE > 1`.)